# Post limit on Facebook friend's wall with open graph api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am building an app using open graph api (PHP sdk). I publish on my friends's wall through this loop :

```
// Where $ids is my array of friends ids
foreach($ids as $id) {
    $facebook->api('/'.$id.'/feed', 'post', array(
        'message' => 'my message',
        'link' => 'my link',
        'picture' => 'my picture')
    );
}
```

I know that before Facebook use a dynamic limit we could find in app "insight". It seems deprecated today. So i wonder if is there a limit for my stuff ? Can i loop 1000 entries without limitations ? I can't find any informations about this.

Thx

Comment: It's not live right now, but i would start to prepare for the ["February 2013 Breaking Changes"](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)(bottom of the page). Facebook will remove the ability to post to friends walls with graph api. This can already be enabled right now inside app settings.

Comment: FYI: The ability to post to other user’s walls will be removed next February – https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013

Comment: Ok thanks guys. It's a big change i'll consider it right now

Answer (score 0):

Im afraid to inform you that this will no longer work since the https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013

however there is a workaround, in order to get similar results you can **tag** your friends on  posts, this way it would still display on their news feed.

An example of application that does that with the tags is:

http://sharetheweight.com.au/fbShareApp.php

This will tags your friends and will appear on Facebook with the *with* and will only appear to the news feed of the users you selected since it will create a user group with privacy enabled to just that group